# iteration in pandas.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe which has three fields: 'location', 'sex', and 'category '.

The field location has a value between 1 and 1000.
The field sex has a value of either 'm' or 'f'
The field category has a value between 1 and 600. 
I want a count of items for each location, each sex for a list of category value, say `[5,35,64,100, 216]`

I have tried something like:

```
result5=df.loc[(df.sex=='M')&(df.category==5)].groupby(['location','category'])count()
```

I can write the same code for other wanted values in the category list as well.
But it seems very repetitive

I have also tried something like:

```
for i in [5,35,64,100, 216]:
    if i=5:
       result5=df.loc[(df.sex=='M')&(df.category==i)].groupby(['location','category'])count()
```

etc.
It seems very repetitive as well.

Can you please help me with a simple set of codes that can iterate the process?
many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First filter data by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then aggregate by all 3 columns with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
L = [5,35,64,100, 216]
df1 = (df[df.location.isin(L)]
                .groupby(['location','sex','category'])
                .size()
                .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, but I got the data format as:
location, category and count as three columns.
What I really need is location and each category, for example category5, category35, category64 etc as columns, then have count in each cell.
can you teach me how to do that please? Many thanks!